# Вставка в массив на позицию

Tags: c#, массивы

Дан массив целых чисел, число k и значение Y. Необходимо вставить в массив на позицию с индексом k элемент, равный Y, сдвинув все элементы, имевшие индекс не менее k, вправо. Последний элемент массива исчезает. Написать в С#.

Comment: вы еще забыли "выполнить и доложить"

Comment: @DreamChild: из этого вышла бы неплохая метка :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну держите, сами просили.

```
arr.Take(k).Concat(new[] { Y }).Concat(arr.Skip(k).Take(arr.Count() - k - 1))
```

Comment: какое издевательство))))

Comment: Круто, `LINQ` в таких делах очень хорош. Интересно, кстати, какой соптимизированный `Expression Tree` получится для этой штуки.

Comment: @Котик: я не сообразил, как убрать `.Count()`, а вот если оптимизатор заметит парные `Take(k)` и `Skip(k)`, будет офигенно.